# Understanding MongoDB Aggregation

Tags: mongodb

Pretend that our collection has 1M document 
Now if i do aggregation like this:

```
db.users.aggregate({
    $group: {
        _id : "$gender",
        avgAge : { $avg : "$age" }
    }
})
```

then how it will prepare the data for me? 
 Say i have a index on the id but not on the gender so is it gonna read all the 1M documents? if so then how does it scale?

Answer (score 0):

Indices can speed up an aggregation when utilized in a `$match` or a `$sort` stage at the beginning of a pipeline.

With your example, no index will be used, since you don't use either. So every document will be accessed.